# CPT category post/content is not showing on my page, Please review my coede

Tags: wp-query

```
    <?php
    $args = array( 
//'posts_per_page' => 99,
'post_type' => 'course',
'category_name' => 'Consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod', //<-- custom post type category name, I have used it to find its content
'orderby' => 'date',
//'order' => 'ASC',
'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
'paged' => $paged);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if ($loop->have_posts()) :
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title(sprintf('<li><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', 
    esc_url(get_permalink())), '</a></li>');
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

I have tried this with default post type "post" without category name its working. But woth CPT, custom post type and custom taxonomy its not working.

Comment: And do you use built in categories for this post type?

Comment: @Krzysiek Dróżdż, yes with built in categories of dafult post type, its working. but with custom post type categorises with custom taxonomy not working.

Comment: But in your code you use built in categories for CPT. Are you really tagging these posts with built in categories or do you use some custom taxonomy?

Comment: @Krzysiek Dróżdż, 'post_type' => 'course' is a custom post type. Please correct if I am wrong

Comment: But category_name is built in taxonomy registered for built in posts...

Comment: @Krzysiek Dróżdż, Oh I see. I have changed it and its working thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84029/discussion-between-super-model-and-krzysiek-drozdz).

Answer (score 1):

To display the content, you can use `the_content()`, like this

```
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title(sprintf('<li><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', 
    esc_url(get_permalink())), '</a></li>');
    the_content(); // render content
endwhile;
```

Comment: I’m afraid that’s not an answer to this question...